# AngularJS - Binding to array not being reflected in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a directive that can render a collection of controls.

Each control is a directive called `fsFilter` - in my controller that controls the parent element, i bind the `filters` array to an array in the parent scope.

This works fine and when the directive is first compiled renders the child directives.

When I add a new object to the `filters` array in the parent scope, i can see (using `$watch`) that the bound array inside the child scope has changed however the change in the property hasn't "recompiled".  I've tried adding `$apply` and using an `addFilter` method to the directive's scope and rather hackishly calling `element.scope()` to call the function directly. This as you'd expect updates the array but still no recomposition.  This too will not let me call `$apply` directly after adding the new object to the array.

This is my directive

```
.directive('fsFilterCollection', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',        
        priority: 1002,
        scope: {
            filters: "="           
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, testFactory) {
            $scope.filterIndex = 0;

            $scope.filterClosedFn = function ($event, filterdata) {
                $event.stopPropagation();
                $scope.filters = $scope.filters.filter(function (el) { return el.name != filterdata });
                console.log("filter closed" + testFactory.sayHello());
            }

            if ($scope.filters) {
                angular.forEach($scope.filters, function (el) { el.index = $scope.filterIndex++; });
            }

            $scope.addFilter = function () {  
                if (arguments.length == 1 && angular.isObject(arguments[0])) {
                    $scope.filters.push(arguments[0]);
                }
                else {
                    $scope.filters.push({ filterType: "String" });
                }             
            }
        },
        template: function (element, attr) {
            return  '<div>'+
                    '   <div ng-repeat="filter in filters">'+
                    '     <div>',
                    '          <div fs-filter keepopen="true" filter-closed-fn="filterClosedFn" isopen="isopen" keepopen="true" filterdata="filter.filterdata" fs-filter actions="true" filter-type="String"></div>' +
                    '       </div>'+
                    '   </div>'+
                    '</div>'
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {

            $scope.$watch('filters', function () {
                // reindex
                $scope.filterIndex = 0;
                angular.forEach($scope.filters, function (el) { el.index = $scope.filterIndex++; });
            },true);
        }
    }
})
```

This is my parent controller:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('development-beta', ['ui.select', 'ui.bootstrap','firespace.filtercontrol','ngSanitize']);
        myAppModule.controller('fs-controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.filters = [
                { filterType:"String" }
            ];            

            $scope.addFilter = function () {
                $("#myfilters *[fs-filter]").scope().addFilter();
            }
        }]);
```

Also, if can tell me whether updating the bound array in the parent scope is the correct way of doing this?  i read a bit about using a factory, but as it's a singleton i couldn't see how each directive's scope could be managed without passing the $scope into each call?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, having a bad day.

If anyone else has problems with ng-repeat not binding, might, just might have something to do with...

```
 template: function (element, attr) {
            return  '<div>'+
                    '   <div ng-repeat="filter in filters">'+
                    '     <div>',
                    '          <div fs-filter keepopen="true" filter-closed-fn="filterClosedFn" isopen="isopen" keepopen="true" filterdata="filter.filterdata" fs-filter actions="true" filter-type="String"></div>' +
                    '       </div>'+
                    '   </div>'+
                    '</div>'
        },
```

In the template I'd accidentally used a ',' (comma) instead of concatenating it with '+' (LINE 4)

I really hope this helps someone some day.

Comment: :) Sure, I really hope this helps someone some day.

Comment: :) let's hope - i wasted 45 minutes thinking it was broken

Comment: I too was wondering what happened here, never noticed the ","